Issues implementing a custom layer in Tensorflow
I copied this code from tensorflow's documentation for implementing a custom layer:
import tensorflow as tf
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                         self.num_outputs])

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)

layer = MyDenseLayer(10)

_ = layer(tf.zeros([10, 5])) # Calling the layer `.builds` it.
print([var.name for var in layer.trainable_variables])

When I attempt to run the code in Spyder using Tensorflow 2.17.0, I get a recursion error.
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

The traceback is a follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xoxo/Documents/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):


Good point, it is indeed wrong in the TF docs.
The arguments of function add_weight has been reordered and the documentation has not been updated. You just need to add a name= before "kernel", and it should work (at least it does for me on tf2.16.1).
So the correct code (which simply prints "kernel"):
import tensorflow as tf
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name="kernel",
                                      shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                             self.num_outputs])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)

layer = MyDenseLayer(10)

_ = layer(tf.zeros([10, 5])) # Calling the layer `.builds` it.
print([var.name for var in layer.trainable_variables])

